# Compare a list of numbers with a variable

Tags: scheme, racket

The function below is intended to compare every number in a list (2nd parameter) with the first parameter and for every num in the list that is greater than the second param, count it and return the total amount of elements in the list that were greater than the 'threshold'

The code I have doesn't run because I have tried to learn how recursion in Dr. Racket works, but I can't seem to understand. I am just frustrated so just know the code below isn't supposed to be close to working; functional programming isn't my thing, haha.

```
(define (comp-list threshold list-nums)
  (cond [(empty? list-nums) 0]
        [(cons?  list-nums) (let {[my-var 0]}
                              (map (if (> threshold (first list-nums)) 
                                       threshold 2) list-nums ))]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't use lambda of foldl (and is recursive) - can you understand how it works?

```
(define (comp-list threshold list-nums)
  (cond [(empty? list-nums) 0]
        [else
         (cond [(> (car list-nums) threshold) (+ 1 (comp-list threshold (cdr list-nums)))]
               [else (comp-list threshold (cdr list-nums))])]))
```

Tested:

```
> (comp-list 1 '(1 1 2 2 3 3))
4
> (comp-list 2 '(1 1 2 2 3 3))
2
> (comp-list 3 '(1 1 2 2 3 3))
0
```

Comment: Why a new `cond` in the `else` part of the first `cond`? A `cond` with 3 test-expressions would be more readable.

Comment: I just did that to separate out the end condition.

Answer (score 1):

`map` takes a procedure as first argument and applied that to every element in the given list(s). Since you are counting something making a list would be wrong.

`foldl` takes a procedure as first argument, the starting value as second and one or more lists. It applies the procedure with the elements and the starting value (or the intermediate value) and the procedure get to decide the next intermediate value. eg. you can use it to count a list:

```scm
(define (my-length lst)
  (foldl (lambda (x acc) (+ acc 1))
         0
         lst))

(my-length '(a b c)) ; ==> 3
```

You can easily change this to only count when `x` is greater than some threshold, just evaluate to `acc` to keep it unchanged when you are not increasing the value.

**UPDATE**

A recursive solution of `my-length`:

```
(define (my-length lst)
  ;; auxiliary procedure since we need
  ;; an extra argument for counting
  (define (aux lst count)
    (if (null? lst)
        count
        (aux (cdr lst)
             (+ count 1))))
  ;; call auxiliary procedure
  (aux lst 0))
```

The same alteration to the procedure to `foldl` have to be done with this to only count in some circumstances.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 'lambda' is doing and what does 'acc' mean?

Comment: `lambda` is just the secret word for making procedure.. `((lambda (x) (+ x 10)) 5) ; ==> 15`. `acc` is just a common argument name to indicate it's a accumulated value. You can choose whatever you want to call them, but using some common names that indicate what they are used for is  a nice way of making the code easier to read. eg. `lst` is a common name for a argument that suppsoed to take a list of something.

Comment: I haven't learned fold1 yet and barely the lambda keyword. Is there anyway I could use recursion to check if each list item is less than a certain value?

Comment: @CompScientist In the above lambda function, the new result is always `(+ acc 1)`, regardless of what `x` is. But you could chose to return either `acc` or `(+ acc 1)` depending on `x` being lesser or greater than a threshold.

Comment: @CompScientist Added a recursive version. You still need to fix it to use the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (comp-list threshold list-nums)
  (cond 
    [(empty? list-nums)  ; there are 0 elements over the threshold in an empty list
     0]
    [(cons?  list-nums)  ; in a constructed list, we look at the the first number
     (cond
       [(< threshold (first list-nums)) 
        (+ 1                                        ; the first number is over
           (comp-list threshold (rest list-nums))]  ; add the rest 
       [else 
        (comp-list threshold (rest list-nums))])])) ; the first number is lower
```

Comment: Well put! I will study this and see how you came to this conclusion, thank you.

Comment: I used the design recipe in HtDP: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html

Answer (score 0):

### A simple functional start

```
#lang racket

(define (comp-list threshold list-nums)
  (define (my-filter-function num)
    (<  num threshold))
  (length (filter my-filter-function list-nums)))
```

### Replacing `define` with `lambda`

```
#lang racket

(define (comp-list threshold list-nums)
  (length (filter (lambda (num) (< num threshold))
                  list-nums)))
```

### Racket's implementation of `filter`

In **DrRacket** highlighting the name of a procedure and right clicking and selecting "*jump to definition in other file*" will allow review of the source code. The source code for `filter` is instructive:

```
  (define (filter f list)
    (unless (and (procedure? f)
                 (procedure-arity-includes? f 1))
      (raise-argument-error 'filter "(any/c . -> . any/c)" f))
    (unless (list? list)
      (raise-argument-error 'filter "list?" list))
    ;; accumulating the result and reversing it is currently slightly
    ;; faster than a plain loop
    (let loop ([l list] [result null])
      (if (null? l)
        (reverse result)
        (loop (cdr l) (if (f (car l)) (cons (car l) result) result)))))
```